# Normal image and selected image? jQuery or css required?

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, onclick

Sorry if this is already posted, but I really need your help.

What I want is following:

Let's say I have this image as normal image that can be clicked.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGYyG.png

Now let's say, when I click on that image it will fade this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUPmP.png

Can anyone tell me how to code this on click image selection ? Or if it cannot be onclick then how else, please?

EDIT:
Also I forgot to mention. If I have 2 selecting choices...
And if I click one choice it fades in and if I select choice 2, choice 1 should fade out and choice 2 fade in like it should...

Comment: just FYI, you can achieve that with CSS3 on all modern browsers.

Comment: Do you need the fade image to stay same after once you click on first image? or you just need the image to fade only when it click and back to the normal image after??

Comment: Updated a bit. Yes it should FadeIn and stay faded unless choice 2 is selected. Then choice 2 fades in and choice 1 fades out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming by fade, you mean an animated fade, you can use the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="something" class="theImage" style="height: 242px; width: 194px; background: url(http://i.imgur.com/QW15C.png);">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SOd1W.png" />
</div>

<div id="somethingElse" class="theImage" style="height: 242px; width: 194px; background: url(http://i.imgur.com/QW15C.png);">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SOd1W.png" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.theImage img').click(function(){
      var current = ($(this).parent().attr('id') == 'something') ? 'somethingElse' : 'something';console.log(current);
      $(this).fadeOut();
      $('#'+current + ' img').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

This will show the default image to start off with, then fade out to show the background image of it's container when clicked. You may decide to use different HTML elements depending on your situation.

Comment: It works but I forgot to mention that if there is more then one image. So if I pick one it fades to select, if I click another it fades to select and previous one doesnt fade back to unselected...

Comment: I've modified it to work with another image - you can extend this to use as many as you need

Answer (score 1):

One way (there are several):

Include both images as tags (not background images) wrapped inside a div:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/120423012508-merkel-sarkozy-c1-main.jpg" id="img1" />
    <img src="http://d2o307dm5mqftz.cloudfront.net/1005866/1334968885891/Perfect%20Gift%20No%20Pink_300x250.jpg" id="img2" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    height:242px;
    width:194px;
}      
#wrapper img{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    height:242px;
    width:194px;
} 
#img1{display:none;}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', function (event){
    $('#wrapper img').fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: This will fade the first out *while* the second fades in. You can't do that by just swapping the src attribute, so you'd need 2 images.

Comment: I don't get it...
http://jsfiddle.net/gGgYv/

I copied what you said but images are not over eachother...

Comment: @NenadNovakovic: sorry for the mess. I've cleaned it up and tested in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DQUGy/

Comment: That is very nice and smooth but I've updated my question a little bit. This is my problem now... http://jsfiddle.net/NuLPy/1/

If there are 2 options to select, selecting one fades in, selecting another one fades in as well, but previous should fadeout on select of another image (choice).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imagelist = ["http://i.imgur.com/SOd1W.png","http://i.imgur.com/QW15C.png"];

    $('.img1').click(function(e) {   
             var myimage = imagelist [Math.floor(Math.random()*imagelist .length)];
             $('.img1').attr('src', myimage );

    });
});
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mY5qc/8/)... Source [simple image randomizer with jQuery by Brian Cray](http://briancray.com/2009/12/28/simple-image-randomizer-jquery/)

Alternatively you can use CSS3 as well. See more about [A Simple Fade with CSS3](http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/)

Comment: Um in demo... It fadesIn and fadesOut same image... I have no clues with jquery so if you don't mind to put fadeIn 2nd image and fadeOut if I have one more image for selecting as choice...

Comment: then you should get all the images from somewhere. May be put them in array

Comment: Great... is that this :D
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Cause I see there some array for text , God knows how to use with images.

Comment: try something like **var imglist = ["img1","img2"];**

Comment: @NenadNovakovic: I did updated the answer. Think that is what you need. You can add as many as images to array and randomize them on click

Answer (score 1):

Use This Javascript

```
function Image(imageId)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById(imageId);
    if(obj.alt=='Fade'){
       obj.src="image1.jpg";     
       obj.alt = "Unfadde";
     }
    else
     {
       obj.src="image2.jpg";     
       obj.alt = "Fade";
      }  
 }
```

and HTML

```
<img src="image1.jpg" onclick=Image("image") id="image" name="image" alt="Fade" />
```

Comment: This is intereesting, but it doesnt fade in/out. And also, if I have more then one image click on 1st replace image and remain selected. Click on 2nd replace the image and remain selected and previous image remain selected as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like job for jQuery [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Here is code
http://jsfiddle.net/ZzDJ8/

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple in CSS, you need to give the image an active pseudoclass:

.img {background: url(firstimg.png);}

.img:active {background: url(clickimg.png);}

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/J6kJh/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5ftGz/

Nope, sorry. That is only active on click, doesn't handle it as active/selected item.

Comment: Ah okay, so you need a toggle-like button

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="a.png" id="MyImg" />
```

jquery:

```
$("#MyImg").click(function() { $(this).attr("src","b.png") });
```

Comment: Can you make the transition fade?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SOd1W.png" onclick="$(this).fadeOut().attr('src','http://i.imgur.com/QW15C.png').fadeIn();">
```

Comment: It is fine as well... But when I have 2 images and select first one and then another one, they both stay faded in "selected".